# Make an html paragraph bigger without making it bold

Tags: html, css

I have a problem regarding the p tag and some css.
I want to enlarge the text without it becoming bold.
But if I'm exceeding 17.5 px or higher, the text becomes bold, and I don't want that.

Here are the codes I'm using (very very basic)

```
<p class="homepage">
  I'm text
</p>
```

Than, some very basic css,

```
.homepage{
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Is there a possibility to just force the font being a standard width?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's working fine. it's not become bold, bigger font may be look like it's bold.

Comment: Try to add font-weight:lighter, maybe will help you a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a font with more font-weight's. You can not only have normal or **bold**. some fonts can have very light to very big (100 to 900)

```
font-weight:100; /*is very light*/
font-weight:900; /*is very big*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/Lw8CT/1/

Not every font knows each of this weights. You can have a look at Google fonts (for example) and search fonts you like.

But to answer your question: Your font does not become bold, when you make the font-size bigger. It just look bigger.

Comment: *Most* fonts commonly used on web pages have only weights 400 and 700. Very few have 100 or 900. Almost no font has all font weights from 100 to 900.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @JukkaK.Korpela when you have more insight in this topic, feel free to edit the answer. You are right, this could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Text shouldn't become bold - it's just bigger and that's why it looks bolder than smaller text. Not only outer width of font stretches, but also lines become thicker (and as result - visually bolder).

Comment: Okay, but isn't it weird that the difference between 17.4px (http://puu.sh/7wbU2.png) and 17.5 (http://puu.sh/7wbXs.png) is so huge?

Comment: One is rounded up and one is rounded down. Try making the 17.5px text bold - you'll definitely see a difference.